# Deadlock: property mode in keylock resource-list differs from owner-list mode

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, deadlock, error-log

I have been working with some deadlocks situations in our application recently and have a new case which seems odd to me. The error log displays this (without execution stacks which doesn't matter at this time I believe):

```
deadlock-list
  deadlock victim=process84db88
   process-list
    process id=process84db88 taskpriority=0 logused=0 waitresource=KEY: 11:72057594409844736 (8194443284a0) waittime=4685 ownerId=3632385974 transactionname=SELECT lasttranstarted=2011-12-07T16:21:16.287 XDES=0x32f68fca0 lockMode=S schedulerid=6 kpid=6392 status=suspended spid=93 sbid=0 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=0 lastbatchstarted=2011-12-07T16:21:16.287 lastbatchcompleted=2011-12-07T16:21:16.287 clientapp=.Net SqlClient Data Provider hostname=DE-1809 hostpid=4156 loginname=XXX isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=3632385974 currentdb=11 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671088672 clientoption2=128056
     executionStack
      ........   
    process id=process47bdc8 taskpriority=0 logused=240604 waitresource=KEY: 11:72057594409844736 (829df5d1e88e) waittime=4681 ownerId=3632397262 transactionname=UPDATE lasttranstarted=2011-12-07T16:21:26.100 XDES=0x2f00b93c0 lockMode=X schedulerid=1 kpid=6568 status=suspended spid=88 sbid=0 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=2 lastbatchstarted=2011-12-07T16:21:25.640 lastbatchcompleted=2011-12-07T16:21:25.640 clientapp=.Net SqlClient Data Provider hostname=DE-1809 hostpid=4156 loginname=XXX isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=3632397262 currentdb=11 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=673316896 clientoption2=128056
     executionStack
      .........  
   resource-list
    keylock hobtid=72057594409844736 dbid=11 objectname=dbo.OurTable indexname=PK_OurTable id=lock1d9aa0b00 mode=X associatedObjectId=72057594409844736
     owner-list
      owner id=process47bdc8 mode=X
     waiter-list
      waiter id=process84db88 mode=S requestType=wait
    keylock hobtid=72057594409844736 dbid=11 objectname=dbo.OurTable indexname=PK_OurTable id=lock1a56cb580 mode=U associatedObjectId=72057594409844736
     owner-list
      owner id=process84db88 mode=S
     waiter-list
      waiter id=process47bdc8 mode=X requestType=convert
```

The lock is happening on a key in the same clustered index in one of our tables. What confuses me a little bit is the mode in the last keylock row in the resource-list.

It says: **mode=U** while the owner in the corresponding owner-list says: **mode=S**.

How should I read this? These two modes are usually the same. How can these modes differ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would interpret that as meaning that `process47bdc8` has a `U` lock on that resource and is waiting to convert that to an `X` lock but can't as `process84db88` already has an `S` lock on it.

`S` locks and `U` locks [are compatible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186396.aspx).

Comment: You are probably right Martin. Process process84db88 only selects some data, is not running in a transaction, and OurTable is in that query as a join. Since it is a lock on the same index, do you know how SQL Server acquire its locks? Can it obtain one lock from the select query but fail on the second requested by the same query? Shouldn't be acquire all locks or none. For me it seems working like: Request lock 1, request granted step forward and request lock 2, request declined you have to wait on lock 2 but still hold on to lock 1. This can't be possible right?

Comment: @John - Yes at `readcommitted` it will take out row `S` locks individually as it reads the data and release them immediately as soon as the data is read. You can use SQL Server Profiler to trace the lock acquired and released events to see this (on a development server as this trace can generate a lot of data)

Comment: @John - BTW: If you do trace in Profiler you might see the row `S` locks aren't always taken out. [The explanation for that behavior is in this article](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/11/01/read-committed-shared-locks-and-rollbacks.aspx)

Comment: Deadlock happens because two processes waits on each other for a certain amount of time right? So if process1 obtains a lock on key1 it should release that lock once the data is read? Then if process2 holds a lock to key2 and process1 requests a lock on key2 process2 can just wait until process1 has read the data on key1 and acquire its own lock, finish its updates/inserts..whatever and release all its locks and then process1 are free to go and continue reading the data on key2? I hope you understand anything of what I am writing here.. :)

Comment: @John - Are you asking why the deadlock can't be resolved by `process84db88` simply releasing its S lock as it has already read the data? Not sure actually. Good question! Tracing the lock events in Profiler should shed some light on this.

Comment: When working with isolation level Read Committed, that is my exact (new) question. The answer could be that if `process84db88` would release its shared lock then some other process could modify that data while `process84db88` continues to read other data from other pages/rows and then the result from that query would be "false" in a way.

Comment: @John - [One possible explanation might be this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2007/05/31/read-committed-and-large-objects.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) might provide an explanation:

> To avoid this potential deadlock problem, update (U) locks are used.
>   Only one transaction can obtain an update (U) lock to a resource at a
>   time. If a transaction modifies a resource, the update (U) lock is
>   converted to an exclusive (X) lock. Otherwise, the lock is converted
>   to a shared-mode lock.

So one transaction (probably the first) that requests a Shared lock ends up holding an Update lock instead.  The Update lock merely gives the transaction the option to convert to an eXclusive lock if it wants to do an update.

This mechanism helps if two transactions read and then write to the same row. In your case, there are two rows in play. The first transaction has an exclusive lock on row A, and is waiting to convert to an exclusive lock on row B.  The second transaction has a shared lock on row B, that's really an Update lock, and it's waiting for an exclusive lock on row A.